# Bower fails silently at extraction phase

Tags: node.js, npm, extract, bower, bower-install

There is a problem I am facing with bower. It is failing constantly at bower extract phase. Tried many things for last week but not able to extract that .tgz file, although bower is able to download it fully but just not able to extract it. Tried giving full permission to temp folder where it is getting downloaded, even changed temp folder but still not working. Couldn't find any solution to it in git forum.

On my adjacent system of colleague's system, it is working fine from download to extraction.

```
progress      lib#* received 13.1MB of 13.5MB downloaded, 97%

bower progress      lib#* received 13.4MB of 13.5MB downloaded, 99%![enter image description here][1]
bower extract       lib#* latest-release-evolve-psi2.tgz
bower ENOENT        ENOENT, readdir 'C:\temp\userid\bower\lib-1304-bSbOIZ,function () {     if (cal
led) {       return;     }      removeFunction(path);      c
alled = true;   }'

Stack trace:
Error: ENOENT, readdir 'C:\temp\userid\
bower\lib-1304-bSbOIZ,function () {
    if (called) {
      return;
    }

    removeFunction(path);

    called = true;
  }'

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (D:\nodejs\node_modules\bower-
canary\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:74:17)
    at Logger.analytics.setup.then.updateNotifier.packageNam
e (D:\nodejs\node_modules\bower-canary\bin\bower:114:22)
    at Logger.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Logger.emit (D:\nodejs\node_modules\bower-canary\node
_modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
    at D:\nodejs\node_modules\bower-canary\lib\commands\inst
all.js:35:16
    at _rejected (D:\nodejs\node_modules\bower-canary\node_m
odules\q\q.js:797:24)
    at Promise.then.self.promiseDispatch.threw (D:\nodejs\no
de_modules\bower-canary\node_modules\q\q.js:823:30)
    at Promise.when (D:\nodejs\node_modules\bower-canary\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\nodejs\node_modul
es\bower-canary\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41)
    at messages (D:\nodejs\node_modules\bower-canary\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:557:44)

System info:
Bower version: 1.3.0
Node version: 0.8.21
OS: Windows_NT 6.1.7601 ia32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Issue solved. Issue was with older version of node 0.8. Node 0.8 was not installing files in NPM folder in appdata/roaming/npm.
After installing node 0.10, it is working now. 
Issue closed.